# Unable to create folder and files in sd card in android 7 programmatically even after providing all necessary permissions

Tags: android

I am trying to move all media files from internal memory to sd card but when I a mtrying to create a folder in sdcard it is not getting created. Please find the below code. I have provided all necessary permissions in program before trying to create folder in sdcard. Yet the folder is not getting created.

```
AndroidManifest.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.rudra.copyfiles">

    **<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />**

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

activity_main.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ToInternalMemory"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Move all Files to Internal Memory"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ToSDCard" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/console"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/ToSDCard"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ToSDCard"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Move all media files to SD card"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/ToInternalMemory"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/console" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

MainActivity.java

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button moveToSDCard, moveToInternalMemory;
    EditText console;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        **if(ExternalStorageUtil.isExternalStorageMounted()) {
            // Check whether this app has write external storage permission or not.
            int writeExternalStoragePermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            // If do not grant write external storage permission.
            if (writeExternalStoragePermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Request user to grant write external storage permission.
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
            }**

            moveToSDCard = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ToSDCard);
            moveToInternalMemory = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ToInternalMemory);
            console = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.console);

            moveToSDCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    String privateDirPath = ExternalStorageUtil.getPrivateCacheExternalStorageBaseDir(getApplicationContext());
                    File dir1 = new File("/storage");
                    File dir2 = searchFolder(dir1);

                    ArrayList<File> f1 = getSongs(new File("/sdcard"));
                    for (File f : f1) {
                        console.setText(f.getName());
                        System.out.println(dir2.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + f.getName());
                        File newFile = new File(dir2.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + f.getName());

                        console.setText(moveFiles(f, newFile));
                    }

                }

            });

        }
                moveToInternalMemory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        File dir1 = new File("/sdcard/AllMediaFiles");
                        if (!dir1.exists()) {
                            dir1.mkdir();

                        }
                        ArrayList<File> f1 = getSongs(new File("/storage"));
                        for (File f : f1) {
                            console.setText(f.getName());
                            System.out.println(dir1.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + f.getName());
                            File newFile = new File(dir1.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + f.getName());

                            moveFiles(f, newFile);
                        }
                    }
                });

    }

    public ArrayList<File> getSongs(File Root) {
        ArrayList<File> al = new ArrayList<File>();
        File[] files = Root.listFiles();

//            System.out.println(files.length);
        for (File singleFile : files) {
            try {
//                    System.out.println(singleFile.getName());
                if (singleFile.getName().startsWith(".")) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (singleFile.isDirectory()) {
                    al.addAll(getSongs(singleFile));
                } else {
                    if (singleFile.getName().endsWith(".mp3") || singleFile.getName().endsWith(".wav") || singleFile.getName().endsWith(".m4a") || singleFile.getName().endsWith(".mp4")) {
                        al.add(singleFile);
                    }
                }
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
//                System.out.println(singleFile.getName() + "is null.");
                continue;
            }

        }
        return al;
    }

    public File searchFolder(File dir1) {
        {




            File[] files = dir1.listFiles();
            File dir2 = null;
//            System.out.println(files.length);
            for (File singleFile : files) {
                try {
                    System.out.println(singleFile.getName());
                    if (singleFile.getName().startsWith(".")) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (singleFile.isDirectory() && isExternalStorageWritable()) {
                        boolean s = isExternalStorageWritable();

                        getPublicAlbumStorageDir("Debasis");
                        if (singleFile.getName().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("android")) {

                            dir2 = new File(singleFile.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath()+File.pathSeparator+"AllMediaFiles");
                            if (!dir2.exists()) {
                                dir2.mkdir();
                                System.out.println(dir2);
                                console.setText("Folder Created Successfully in SD card");
                                boolean g = dir2.exists();
                                return dir2;

                            }
                        } else {
                            dir2 = searchFolder(singleFile);
                            if(dir2.exists())
                            {
                                return dir2;
                            }
                        }

                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }


            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    public String moveFiles(File inputFile, File newFile)
    {
        try
        {
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(newFile);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int read;
            while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            in.close();
            in = null;

            // write the output file
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            out = null;
            if(newFile.exists())
            {
           //     inputFile.delete();
                return newFile.getName()+" moved successfully";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (requestCode == 1) {
            int grantResultsLength = grantResults.length;
            if (grantResultsLength > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You grant write external storage permission. Please click original button again to continue.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You denied write external storage permission.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

    /* Checks if external storage is available for read and write */
    public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /* Checks if external storage is available to at least read */
    public boolean isExternalStorageReadable() {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) ||
                Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    public File getPublicAlbumStorageDir(String albumName) {
        // Get the directory for the user's public pictures directory.
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), albumName);
        if (!file.mkdirs()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Directory not created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
        return file;
    }
}

ExternalStorageUtil.java

package com.rudra.copyfiles;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.StatFs;

import java.io.File;

/**
 * Created by Jerry on 1/22/2018.
 */

public class ExternalStorageUtil {

    // Check whether the external storage is mounted or not.
    public static boolean isExternalStorageMounted() {

        String dirState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(dirState))
        {
            return true;
        }else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Check whether the external storage is read only or not.
    public static boolean isExternalStorageReadOnly() {

        String dirState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(dirState))
        {
            return true;
        }else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }


    // Get private external storage base directory.
    public static String getPrivateExternalStorageBaseDir(Context context, String dirType)
    {
        String ret = "";
        if(isExternalStorageMounted()) {
            File file = context.getExternalFilesDir(dirType);
            ret = file.getAbsolutePath();
        }
        return ret;
    }

    // Get private cache external storage base directory.
    public static String getPrivateCacheExternalStorageBaseDir(Context context)
    {
        String ret = "";
        if(isExternalStorageMounted()) {
            File file = context.getExternalCacheDir();
            ret = file.getAbsolutePath();
        }
        return ret;
    }


    // Get public external storage base directory.
    public static String getPublicExternalStorageBaseDir()
    {
        String ret = "";
        if(isExternalStorageMounted()) {
            File file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            ret = file.getAbsolutePath();
        }
        return ret;
    }

    // Get public external storage base directory.
    public static String getPublicExternalStorageBaseDir(String dirType)
    {
        String ret = "";
        if(isExternalStorageMounted()) {
            File file = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(dirType);
            ret = file.getAbsolutePath();
        }
        return ret;
    }

    // Get external storage disk space, return MB
    public static long getExternalStorageSpace() {
        long ret = 0;
        if (isExternalStorageMounted()) {
            StatFs fileState = new StatFs(getPublicExternalStorageBaseDir());

            // Get total block count.
            long count = fileState.getBlockCountLong();

            // Get each block size.
            long size = fileState.getBlockSizeLong();

            // Calculate total space size
            ret = count * size / 1024 / 1024;
        }
        return ret;
    }

    // Get external storage left free disk space, return MB
    public static long getExternalStorageLeftSpace() {
        long ret = 0;
        if (isExternalStorageMounted()) {
            StatFs fileState = new StatFs(getPublicExternalStorageBaseDir());

            // Get free block count.
            long count = fileState.getFreeBlocksLong();

            // Get each block size.
            long size = fileState.getBlockSizeLong();

            // Calculate free space size
            ret = count * size / 1024 / 1024;
        }
        return ret;
    }

    // Get external storage available disk space, return MB
    public static long getExternalStorageAvailableSpace() {
        long ret = 0;
        if (isExternalStorageMounted()) {
            StatFs fileState = new StatFs(getPublicExternalStorageBaseDir());

            // Get available block count.
            long count = fileState.getAvailableBlocksLong();

            // Get each block size.
            long size = fileState.getBlockSizeLong();

            // Calculate available space size
            ret = count * size / 1024 / 1024;
        }`enter code here`
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Mike, there are multiple posts on similar issues and they suggest adding proper permissions which I have done the folders are not getting created. Hence I provided the entire code so that any experienced person can look in depth and suggest a working alternative. Thanks.

Comment: Sure Mike Got it. Will make the question presize. Can you help me out here.

Comment: If you're talking about _removable_ storage, then that's a tricky thing. Have a read through [this blog post from CommonsWare](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/15/storage-situation-removable-storage.html). It's not like accessing the regular internal and external storage areas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removable micro SD cards are write only on modern Android devices if you use the File or FileOutputStream class.

Use Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE to get write access to the card.

Comment: Hi greenapps this solves my problem though as I am able to create files in my Samsung sd card. Can you advice me how to copy files from one internal memory to removable storage as file.rename will not work here.

Comment: Read from one file and write to the other. Copy.

Comment: Any example or link

Comment: Google for how to copy a file.

Answer (score 0):

okay use this, it is work for me

```
  String dirPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    dirPath+="/Android/data/"+context.getPackageName()+"/";
  File file = new File(dirPath)
file.mkdirs();
```

Comment: Hi Tejas, The code suggested by you although works but it creates folder in internal memory and not in my external samsung  32gb sdcard which I have added to my phone. Can you suggest any alternative.

Comment: hello you have check this [link](https://www.journaldev.com/9400/android-external-storage-read-write-save-file)

Comment: Yes I did check the above link. The problem is the methods mentioned in the link are not applicable for removable storage.

Answer (score 0):

One thing is missing in your manifest:

```
<application
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
    ...
```

This will allow to access external storage on Android 10+